# Change Google Maps mapTypeControl style

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm looking for a way to change the styling of the "Map | Satellite" buttons. I've considered and looked for various options, but to no succes so far.

On the [Google Maps Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#ControlModification)-page they do tell about the buttons, and that you can change the visibility or the positioning. However, they do not explain how to change the actual style of the buttons.

I've also been looking at ways to toggle the map with a custom button, but to no succes so far.

Is it possible to change the style of the buttons, and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Create your own [custom map type control](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/controls#CustomControls).

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I however do not know how exactly to call the desired functionality of switching map views, as that was what I was looking for too. Could you give me an example of code of how to bind the functionality of the view change to a custom-made button?